# How to reboot not jailbroken iOS device programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I need to reboot iOS device for automation.
Is there a way to do that automatically using terminal or may be to write simple iOS app which would reboot device on launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do this on a real device, i.e. not the simulator, then I'm almost certain this is impossible. Apple doesn't allow you to do much outside of your sandboxed app, let alone reboot the entire phone.

Comment: I am using deviceconsole tool to get logs from the device. But after some period of time, I can't get any logs even using different tools (deviceconsole, idevicesyslog, IOS console), device just doesn't return anything. The only solution is to reboot the device. Do you think about any solutions?

Comment: What kind of period of time are we talking about here?

Comment: Wow ok. What are you doing for automation? Testing a single app, or something more elaborate?

Comment: Automating one app with Appium. That's very common not resolved issue. Basically device stops returning any logs: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4216

Comment: In source code of Appium server there is timeout which block the process of running tests if "Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time". I will try to disable this condition, and see how it is gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're interested you could reboot via the killswitch in springboard app switcher